# Send data (.CSV file) from SQL Server to Postgres server?

Tags: sql-server, postgresql

I want to extract data from SQL Server using bcp into a `.csv` file, and send the generated file to a PostgreSQL server. The problem is that I can't extract the data from SQL Server because I have to much problems with the date type.

Anyway... I ask someone to tell me another idea (general) to make this work.

I try too with SSIS but is something limited.

Thanks,

:)

Answer (score 0):

Please expand on "I have to much problems with the date type". You should export dates in ISO format.

To export from MS SQL Server, run:

```
bcp "select * from some_table" queryout results.tsv -T -S serverHostName -w
```

(Assuming you're using Windows Authentication). That will give you a tab-separated file in Unicode.

MS SQL Server exports Unicode as UTF-16, and PostgreSQL likes UTF-8, so use iconv to convert:

```
iconv -f UTF16 -t UTF8 results.tsv > results-utf8.tsv
```

You can find iconv-style programs for Windows too.

Then use psql to upload the file to PostgreSQL:

```
psql -c "\copy some_table from 'results-utf8.tsv'"
```

You could also try using a https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Foreign_data_wrappers

Comment: Hi: I apologize for my lack of precision.

Currently developing a .bat that generates the start and end time for the query. But when I run the generated file contains is empty
Any idea what could be?
sqlcmd -S my_server -d my_db -E -Q "select * from alert  where dt > %datetimef% and dt < %last% ;" -s "," -o  "%name%.csv" The %last% and %datetime% format is yyyy-mm-dd, I ise sql server 2008.

Comment: I used too BCP but the problem is the same, when I used bcp  I try to cast (o convert) the data type (to the representatión yyyy-mm-dd), but do not work, the date do not change.

Comment: @RalyMontes is the date column actually a date type?

Comment: Thnks, Naeil. Yes, and my query for bcp is SET @bcpCommand = 'bcp "SELECT cv21, cv22 FROM spa..alertas WHERE dt between '''+@first1+''' and '''+@ultimo+'''" queryout "' And  ulitmo is: set @ultimo=@year+'-'+'0'+@month+'-'+'0'+@day+' 00:00:00.000',  Finally ultimo=yyyy-mm-dd 00:00:00.000 , but do not work. (MS SQL 2008 R2)